# Running multiple pods of go-ethereum with common EFS storage on AWS EKS/kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ethereum, amazon-eks, amazon-efs, go-ethereum

I am trying to run a go-ethereum node on AWS EKS, for that i have used statefulsets with below configuration.
[statefulset.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxyOt.png)

Running`kubectl apply -f statefulset.yaml` creates 2 pods out of which 1 is running and 1 is in CrashLoopBackOff state.
[Pods status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS6ez.png)
After checking the logs for second pod the error I am getting is `Fatal: Failed to create the protocol stack: datadir already used by another process`.
[Error logs i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4rqa.png)

The problem is mainly due to the pods using the same directory to write(geth data) on the persistant volume(i.e the pods are writing to '/data'). If I use a subpath expression  and mount the pod's directory to a sub-directory with pod name(for eg: '/data/geth-0') it works fine.
[statefulset.yaml with volume mounting to a sub directory with podname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxXQA.png)

But my requirement is that all the three pod's data is written at '/data' directory.
Below is my volume config file.
[volume configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGegz.png)

Comment: Each pod will have its own chaindata and that will consume a lot of storage. What i need is that the pods share chaindata between them

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically provision the access point for each of your stateful pod. First create an EFS storage class that support dynamic provision:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-dyn-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
reclaimPolicy: Retain
parameters:
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
  directoryPerms: "700"
  fileSystemId: <get the ID from the EFS console>
```

Update your spec to support claim template:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: geth
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
  ...
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: geth
      ...
      volumeMounts:
      - name: geth
        mountPath: /data
      ...
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: geth
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      storageClassName: efs-dyn-sc
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

All pods now write to their own /data.

Comment: I think that will store each pod's data at different location. Each pod will have its own chaindata and that will consume a lot of storage. What i need is that the pods share chaindata between them. Is it possible ?

Comment: Your application does not support sharing data; given the fact that it already told you `...datadir already used by another process.`. You need to check your application manual if that's possible in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The same directory cannot be reused by multiple instances of go-ethereum, so you have the following options:

1. Use the same persistent volume for each pod and use a subdirectory for each pod
2. Use a separate persistent volume for each pod, then each can use the same `/data` path